# What's difference between these redis starting commands

Tags: linux, redis

- sudo /etc/init.d/redis-server start
- sudo service redis-server start
- sudo systemctl start redis-server
- sudo redis-server --daemonize yes

Comment: The first 3 commands are commands for different [service managers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system_service_management) - rc.d, sysvinit and systemd. Most linux distributions switched to systemd some time ago, so only systemctl is going to be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last one is *"nearest to the metal"*, it directly starts the Redis server process with no special options, and is *"stand-alone"*. I would use this type of command when just *"messing around"* in the Terminal with quick tests and when trying to get an initial configuration tested and running.

The first 3 are all basically wrappers around starting the Redis server process to make it compatible with **systemd** or other Linux startup systems. They potentially add more layers of management, like:

- reporting to the `systemctl` logs
- saving the process id so the process can be killed or restarted
- potentially specifying a different config file
- potentially waiting for other services to become available before starting Redis

I would prefer one of the first three for routine, every-day, managed starting up of Redis on a production system.