# Installing Redis use ./install_server.sh

Tags: redis

when I Execute the command `./install_server.sh` an error has occurred. error message as follow:
This system seems to use systemd.
Please take a look at the provided example service unit files in this directory, and adapt and install them. Sorry!
I don't know how to solve this problem, please help me

```
% cd utils
% ./install_server.sh
```

error message

```
This systems seems to use systemd.
Please take a look at the provided example service unit files in this directory, and adapt and install them. Sorry!
```

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/60671195/2836621

Answer (score 4):

```
vi ./install_server.sh
```

comment it

```
#bail if this system is managed by systemd
#_pid_1_exe="$(readlink -f /proc/1/exe)"
#if [ "${_pid_1_exe##*/}" = systemd ]
#then
#       echo "This systems seems to use systemd."
#       echo "Please take a look at the provided example service unit files in this directory, and adapt and install them. Sorry!"
#       exit 1
#fi
```

Comment: did  u mean comment it?

Comment: This worked, thanks! But why is it so hard from redis developers? :D

Answer (score 0):

you can install  redis-release-6.0 below and try again. try 5.0.5 it was effectived on my computer.I don't know the exact reasons.

Answer (score 0):

#### Steps I followed to make it run in my system

Comment out following lines in `redis-stable/utils/instal_server.sh` file

```
#bail if this system is managed by systemd
#_pid_1_exe="$(readlink -f /proc/1/exe)"
#if [ "${_pid_1_exe##*/}" = systemd ]
#then
#       echo "This systems seems to use systemd."
#       echo "Please take a look at the provided example service unit files in this directory, and adapt and install them. Sorry!"
#       exit 1
#fi
```

After this, you need to install `tcl tk`

> for ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install -y tcl tk`
>
> for RedHat: `sudo yum install tcl tk`

then inside `redis-stable/src`
run `sudo make install`

if it shows error like
`Hint: It's a good idea to run 'make test' ;)`

go back to redis-stable and run `make distclean` and again `sudo make install`

Finally, run the server by running `redis-server`

Atlast to check if Redis is working: `redis-cli ping`

Comment: it is not an error, but an HINT, as the message says!

Answer (score 0):

I assume your question is, "What the heck does this error message mean, and how might I install redis successfully?"

*Error message interpretation*

It sounds like the `./install_server.sh` is not meant to be used for installation on Linux distributions using **systemd**. What is **systemd**? For your purpose, you just need to think of it as, "the mother of all processes." Credit to [opensource.com](https://opensource.com/article/20/4/systemd) for that one.

When you are installing redis on a machine that uses **systemd**, redis seems to want you to install redis as a "service" managed by **systemd**.

To do that, my personal experience with other **systemd** services has taught me that one can try to preparing a "service unit file" for **systemd**. And then:

1. Reload **systemd** configuration `systemctl daemon-reload`
2. Enable the new service unit `systemctl enable something`
3. Start the new service unit `systemctl start something`

I've used Debian so my service unit file went under `/etc/systemd`.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out following lines and run (./install_server.sh) with root.

```
#bail if this system is managed by systemd
#_pid_1_exe="$(readlink -f /proc/1/exe)"
#if [ "${_pid_1_exe##*/}" = systemd ]
#then
#       echo "This systems seems to use systemd."
#       echo "Please take a look at the provided example service unit files in this directory, and adapt and install them. Sorry!"
#       exit 1
#fi
```